# Matlab Formatting

Tags: matlab

I am having a problem in MATLAB where none of my results are coming out as rationals. They come out as below, which is difficult to obtain an accurate answer like this. I tried using format rat, but it did not work.

```
0.47408343868520859671302149178255*v1
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly.  Currently it is hard to know what the problem is, adding code to reproduce the problem tends to clarify a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using symbolic variables since your answer includes a letter ("v1"). If you want to get a numeric result, you can replace the symbolic variables with the *subs* function and convert them to numeric with the *double* function.

```
vi = sym('vi'); % I assume you created something like this at one point
result = 0.47408343868520859671302149178255*vi; %you made some calculations
numeric_result = double(subs(result, vi, 5)) %now you need to provide the real value of the symbolic variable vi, I wrote 5 as an example
```